# Representing a graph in java application

Tags: graph, neo4j, jung, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint

In my application, I've a domain model which is **essentially a graph**. I need to essentially perform the following operations and the send the resulting graph to the client over network

Operations to be performed

1. Filter certain nodes based on business policy
2. Augment with more nodes and relationships (potentially from other data providers

After filtering, I need a serialization mechanism as well. After working with Neo4j and Tinkerpop, I feel Tinkerpop fits well for my usecase as it has

1. In-memory graph support (TinkerGraph)
2. Serialization mechanisms: GraphML, GML and GrapjSON

I am wondering if my understanding is accurate and approach is correct. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds right. I often extract subgraphs and store them in a TinkerGraph for follow-on processing. I also use GraphSON for serialization. Seems like you're on the right track.

Here are 2 good sources for additional information:

- gremlindocs.com
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gremlin-users

Comment: +1. Any additional things I need to be aware of? Any hints or suggestions...may be a lessons learned blog :-)